# Scopes in context of Modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to understand the concept of scopes in Node.js. The fact that `this === global`, when I try the code below

```
//basic1.js file
this.bar = "Bacon";


//basic2.js file
require('./basic1');
console.log(this.bar);
```

and run basic2.js, output is undefined instead of Bacon. Since I am assigning a property bar in global object and as global object is shared by all the node modules, why am I getting undefined as output? Can you help me understand that.

Comment: How do you conclude that `this === global`?

Comment: this === global //true

Comment: Are you testing that in the REPL? It doesn't hold true for files.

Comment: ok. I was trying that in REPL.

Comment: @robertklep if `this` is not global then what is it?

Comment: `this === module.exports` in files.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how node.js interpret modules better to look at [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js):

1. Read source code from file.
2. Wrap source into function call like `function(exports, require, module, __dirname, __filename){ /* source code */ }`
3. Evaluate wrapped code into v8 virtual machine (similar to eval function in browser) and get function.
4. Call function from previous step with overwriting `this` context with `exports`.

Simplified code:

```
var code = fs.readFileSync('./module.js', 'utf-8');
var wrappedCode = `function (exports, require, module, __dirname, __filename) {\n${code}\n}`;
var exports = {};
var fn = vm.runInThisContext(wrappedCode);
var otherArgs = [];
// ... put require, module, __dirname, __filename in otherArgs
fn.call(exports, exports, ...otherArgs);
```